# Are there any alternatives to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I mean a language separate from Java script that can work with and manipulate Html and also do calculation etc just like javascript

Edit: in the browser

Comment: In the browser? (Many languages have HTML/DOM manipulation libraries available, but if you mean manipulating it in the browser as is commonly seen with JS, then your options are severely limited).

Comment: @james yes in the browser

Comment: this shouldn't be so heavily downvoted, strange

Answer (score 4):

[typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) the statically typed alternative developed by microsoft.

[Dart](http://code.google.com/p/dart/) googles imrpoved javascript.

[Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/) some syntatic sugar on top of javascript - but probably the most popular of the three.

Whats wrong with javascript nayway ? Its great, albeit a bit weird to begin with.

Comment: I think this is way not enough for an answer. Please expand it.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev i imagien the question will get closed anyway ...

Comment: Even a closed question can be of help in the future and same holds true for its answers. Please try to keep up the high standard we aim for in stackoverflow.

Comment: Isn't coffeescript compiled from javascript?

Comment: @user521180 compiled to

Comment: Typescript is's really an alternative, as it generates Javascript.

Comment: @Guffa they all do ... but they definitely provide an alternative to writing javscript.

Comment: Any language that's going to run in commonly used web browsers *and* manipulate the DOM, is going to compile to JS, cause no other scripting language is supported worth a damn in browsers.  If they don't need to mess with the document, Silverlight or Flash might be an alternative...but in this case, JS is what it has to end up as.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is the only script language that is supported in all browsers.

There are a lot of libraries and plugins that you can use to generate Javascript without writing all the code yourself, but in the end they all use Javascript.

Micrsoft also supported VBScript in Internet Explorer up to version 9. In IE 10 you have to force the page into compatibility mode to use VBScript.